# How to separate a xts data by dates from a list of xts objects and create a list?

Tags: r, list, xts

To clarify my question here is a reproducible example:

```
ibov <- structure(c(0.029210645, -0.000172395, 0.035483633, -0.011969176,-0.007692018, 0.010634809, 0.027410321, -0.002632171, 0.000878164,0.004689955), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .CLASS = "double", class = c("xts","zoo"), index = structure(c(1041465600, 1041552000, 1041811200,1041897600, 1041984000, 1042070400, 1042156800, 1388016000, 1388102400,1388361600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "IBOV"))
resa <- structure(c(0.010810871, 0, 0.021277441, 0, -0.021277438, 0.010695311,0.010582131, 0.038614857, -0.022989515, 0.022989514, 0.009950331,-0.006253523, -0.011131809, -0.032230311, 0.019084526, 0.027960905,-0.027960898, 0.013885075, 0.006913914, 0.001716716), class = c("xts","zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1041465600,1041552000, 1041811200, 1041897600, 1041984000, 1042070400, 1042156800,1051488000, 1051574400, 1051660800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L,2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("ACES4", "AMBV4")))
resb <- structure(c(0.033371931, -0.066402455, 0.014815083, 0.018215437,0.01647012, -0.009275838, -0.013713674, 0, 0.020007567, 0.017603702,0.02777956, -0.001054296, -0.019169914, -0.005390845, 0.008611465,0.00641028, -0.004268949, -0.025679012, -0.08124767, 0.027822509), class = c("xts", "zoo"), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", index = structure(c(1378080000,1378166400, 1378252800, 1378339200, 1378425600, 1378684800, 1378771200,1388016000, 1388102400, 1388361600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(10L,2L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("AEDU3", "ALLL3")))
lst <- list(resa, resb)
```

How can I separate the `ibov` data into a list like `lst` classified by the same `lst` dates? It should return something like this:

```
bova <- structure(c(0.029210645, -0.000172395, 0.035483633, -0.011969176,-0.007692018, 0.010634809, 0.027410321), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .CLASS = "double", class = c("xts","zoo"), index = structure(c(1041465600, 1041552000, 1041811200,1041897600, 1041984000, 1042070400, 1042156800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(7L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "IBOV"))
bovb <- structure(c(-0.002632171, 0.000878164,0.004689955), .indexCLASS = "Date", tclass = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tzone = "UTC", .CLASS = "double", class = c("xts","zoo"), index = structure(c(1388016000, 1388102400,1388361600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "IBOV"))
newlst <- list(bova, bovb)

> newlst
[[1]]
                   IBOV
2003-01-02  0.029210645
2003-01-03 -0.000172395
2003-01-06  0.035483633
2003-01-07 -0.011969176
2003-01-08 -0.007692018
2003-01-09  0.010634809
2003-01-10  0.027410321

[[2]]
                   IBOV
2013-12-26 -0.002632171
2013-12-27  0.000878164
2013-12-30  0.004689955
```

Any help will be apreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Probably `?split.xts`.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thank you. It helped, as the real data in `lst` and `ibov` have the same periods.

Comment: I mean, it helped as I needed a list of quarterly data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To future reference I used `split` suggested by JoshuaUlrich to create a quarterly `list` of data.

```
ibov <- split(ibov, f = 'months', k = 3)
```

It worked fine with `split` instead of `split.xts`, producing the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
> dt1 <- index(ibov)[index(ibov) %in% index(lst[[1]])]
> dt2 <- index(ibov)[index(ibov) %in% index(lst[[2]])]

> newlst<- list()
> newlst[[1]] <- ibov[dt1,]
> newlst[[2]] <- ibov[dt2,]
> newlst
[[1]]
                   IBOV
2003-01-02  0.029210645
2003-01-03 -0.000172395
2003-01-06  0.035483633
2003-01-07 -0.011969176
2003-01-08 -0.007692018
2003-01-09  0.010634809
2003-01-10  0.027410321

[[2]]
                   IBOV
2013-12-26 -0.002632171
2013-12-27  0.000878164
2013-12-30  0.004689955
```

Comment: Tks for your answer. For data like that one in the example it works great, but I actually have a list of 33 elements so it would be hard!

Comment: The nature of your problem is unclear. "33 elements" ... of what ... in what?

Comment: My real `lst` data have 33 elements, so I need to split the `ibov` data in 33 elements as well. I'm brazilian an my poor english doesn't help! Sorry for that.